# importing access data into visual studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am building a simple visual studio application that basically is going to look up some data.

The problem I have is the data comes from a access file which I connected simply enough. Selected my tables no problem. when I publish the program setup exe fails because it is looking for the access file. So how do I either include the database in the publish file and tell to build from the database that was included or better how do I import the database file into an internal dataset in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Add access file to your solution then in property of the file change "Copy to Output Directory" from "Do not copy" to "Copy if newer" then the file will be in your bin directory.